# rewrite url from http to https using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want  links with https to forward to http, however they must meet the following condition:

Only url in the format https://example.com/non/ and what ever comes after the trailing slash are forwarded to http
 But links without the /non/ condition remain the same

I want to do this using htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^non(/.*)?$ http://{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```